# How to open android application activity from a email?

Tags: android, android-intent

We are sending a user email as a notification. Email body has to Accept and Reject button. We are sending emails from the android applications as well as from web applications to the user.

We want to open our application if the user clicks on the button contained in the email. If a user checks an email from an android device and clicks on the button, the respective activity should be opened for user convenience.

How can I open that activity if the application is installed?

Thanks,

Prashant.

Comment: You need to enable Deep linking https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

Set href link to you button like:  "http://example.com/path"

and set intent filter like following for target activity:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:host="example.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/path"
       android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

I think path is optional.

Also refer: [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ifs) for intent filters